# Why "Now is the time" 50 years after "Donald in Mathmagic Land"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-origin

Reading about [leet speak on Wikipedia in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet_speak) I stumbled upon this "Now is the time" text among several other examples of it.

[image: leet speak example "Now is the time"]

Why this one caught my attention? I clearly recalled having read it in an old (golden old) Disney cartoon called ["Donald in Mathmagic Land"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052751/), one of my favorites of all times. You can [watch the scene online](https://youtu.be/U_ZHsk0-eF0?t=1540), but here you have a cropped clip (from 25:45 to 25:50 approx.) and a frame, just in case:

[image: Frame showing "now is the time"]

[Complete clip "Now is the time" (I know, two dots)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv834.jpg)

Every time I watch it I wonder about the text, if I am missing a literary reference or something... and forget to dig into it minutes later. But, after finding it again in some random place I thought to myself "now is the time to find this out". Well, googling it yields results about song titles long after 1959, the release year of this Donald's cartoon.

I find unlikely the leet speak sample is a reference to this movie so... why the same text around 50 years later? *Now is the time* to what? Is this a phrase or idiom of which I'm unaware?

Comment: Hello, cdlv. Reasonable research would be to look up the history of the expression being used on Google Ngrams. It's an extremely well-known expression, and usually context makes things clear. Probably a salient literary use should be asked for over on Literature SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not really sure this is related to literature, it was just a guess.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, Literature SE. It is asking for a popularisation of a not uncommon expression.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=now+is+the+time%2Cnow+is+the+time+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnow%20is%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnow%20is%20the%20time%20for%3B%2Cc0) show no marked increase in use after 1918.  The KJV (1611)  has '... I have heard thee in a time accepted, and in the day of salvation have I succoured thee: behold, now is the accepted time; behold, now is the day of salvation.' [II Cor 6:2].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was asking for an explanation to this "coincidence" about an English expression (which has been promptly provided by rajah9) and it turns out it has nothing to do with Literature, thanks.

Comment: Literature SE covers inventions, codifications etc by single persons (eg Boswell). I _could_ have close-voted for lack of relevant research. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_Is_the_Time_(disambiguation)) gives the Weller typing drill, along with a lot of song titles (which have possibly popularised the expression more).

Comment: Please stop it. This is verging on harassment. Now that's clear you were wrong on your Literature approach and your pigheaded migration, you use rajah9's answer to obliquely relate it to Literature through Weller, and my own finding on Wikipedia below to suggest that my question was easy to answer and that you __could__ have used **your thousands of rep** to close-vote it... Well, you were not able to answer it and your ngramming was the irrelevant research. You were wrong, that's all. Everybody makes mistakes, not everybody knows when to let it go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party.

From [The Straight Dope](https://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/259/who-originated-now-is-the-time-for-all-good-men/):

> Cecil replies:
>
> From the typewriter it came, and to the typewriter it shall return:
>   the phrase was proposed as a typing drill by a teacher named Charles
>   E. Weller. Incidentally, many typing books now use the variant “Now is
>   the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country”
>   instead, because it exactly fills out a 70-space line if you put a
>   period at the end.

Comment: So this is a typing drill. The coincidence makes all the sense then.

Comment: Yes, the timing works well for a 1960s cartoon. Your truly typed this sentence in the dawn of the IBM Selectric and it was still called typing class.

Comment: It's easy to find the answer... when you know it. Knowing the complete phrase thanks to your answer, I looked for it and it happens to be in Wikipedia, under ["Filler text"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text#Now_is_the_time_for_all_good_men). Doh.

Answer (score 0):

I remember "now is the time" having been used like, "Now is the time for all good men to come to the help of nature", or "Now is the time for all good girls to sing and dance together", etc.  It has, to my knowledge, been used to create a vibe.